# How to display a list of inheritance objects in Angular?

Tags: angular, typescript, oop

I want to display a list of different objects that inherit from the same abstract class in Angular. What is a good practice to do that?

Let's assume the following simple model:

```
abstract class Vehicle {
     wheels: number;
}

class Car extends Vehicle {
     isConvertible: boolean;
}

class Truck extends Vehicle {
     freight: string;
}
```

My approach *works*, but it seems to be pretty ugly and not the oop way.

HTML Template:

```
<ul>
    <li *ngFor="let vehicle of vehicles">
        <p>{{vehicle.wheels}}</p>
        <p *ngIf="isCar(vehicle)">{{asCar(vehicle).isConvertible}}</p>
        <p *ngIf="isTruck(vehicle)">{{asTruck(vehicle).freight}}</p>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Component:

```
@Component({
    [...]
})
export class VehicleInfoComponent{

    @Input() vehicles: Vehicles[];

    public isCar(vehicle: Vehicle): boolean {
         return vehicle instanceof Car;
    }

    public isTruck(vehicle: Vehicle): boolean {
         return vehicle instanceof Truck;
    }

    public asCar(vehicle: Vehicle): Car{
        return vehicle as Car;
    }

    public asTruck(vehicle: Vehicle): Truck{
        return vehicle as Truck;
    }
}
```

Is there a better more oop way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if it is better than yours or if it is any good.
Try and do what you want if you like it. Hopefully, it is useful.

```
@Component({
    [...]
})
export class ActionInfoComponent{

    @Input() vehicles: Vehicles[]

    public getClass(vehicle: Vehicle): string{
         return vehicle.constructor.name
    }
}
```

and HTML

```
<ul>
    <li *ngFor="let vehicle of vehicles">
        <p>{{vehicle.wheels}}</p>
        <p *ngIf="getClass(vehicle) == 'Car'">{{vehicle.isConvertible}}</p>
        <p *ngIf="getClass(vehicle) == 'Truck'">{{vehicle.freight}}</p>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Interesting! I will give it a try. At least I learned something new: The "constructor.name" attribute!

Comment: That won't compile in AOT (i.e. production) mode, because there is no isConvertible property in Vehicle.